# starting NSURLSessionDownloadTask from today extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, today-extension

I have a host app that has a background download session which works perfectly but initiating the download through the today extension I get this error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -995.)

What do I do about it?
Is there even the possibility to start download from today extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-995` is `NSURLErrorBackgroundSessionRequiresSharedContainer`. You have to set [`sharedContainerIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1409450-sharedcontaineridentifier?language=objc) of the `NSURLSessionConfiguration`. See [App Extension Programming Guide: Performing Uploads and Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW2).

Comment: thank you very much rob, for your quick response. no I have not. now i will follow the leads but could you tell me how did you figured out -995 means what? because I couldn't find it !

Comment: Since you're working in Objective-C, just press shift-command-O (the letter "oh", not zero) and search for `NSURLErrorDomain` and then open up header and you'll see these codes defined. If you were working with Swift, Swift headers frustratingly don't include these codes (so you have to create a blank Objective-C project to search for these `NSURLErrorDomain` codes). But since you're using Objective-C, you're golden.

Comment: @Rob: You can also search for the error at https://osstatus.com. E.g. https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-995

Comment: thanks so much guys @Rob,@Dave Weston excellent piece of advices